# PHP FastCGI open_basedir restriction on IIS 7

Tags: php, iis-7, fastcgi

I have two environments on one server, which are separated via EnvironmenteVariable. That part works like a charm (two FastCGI pools with open_basedir has been set up to ApplicationHost

`<application fullPath="C:\path\to\php\php-cgi.exe" arguments="-d open_basedir=C:\path\to\webroot\ENV_DIR">`

and related web.config

`<add name="php" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\path\to\php\php-cgi.exe|-d open_basedir=C:\path\to\webroot\ENV_DIR" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />`).

**Problem** starts with open_basedir restriction for other folder(s) - like **\\path\to\network\folder** or **C:\path\to\webroot\FOLDER** (which is outside the environment folder). How to enable the access to these folder(s)?

Have tried:

- separated php.ini files per environment with open_basedir="multiple;folders"
- add multiple folders to web.config and applicationHost file to arguments like following:

`'... open_basedir="C:\path\to\webroot\ENV_DIR;C:\path\to\webroot\FOLDER"'`

Nothing seams to help.

Comment: [open_basedir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) can only have 1 directory name, and not a semi-colon list of folder names.

Comment: In php.ini file, you are able to add more: under windows separated by ; and under linux separated by :. That's why I ask, is there a way. Cause for some reason, symlink did not work either (could not resolve it)

Comment: You can even add them separated by anything you like..... But if that serves a purpose is unknown!  

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found a solution. Maybe somebody else needs it as well. Instead of using open_basedir, use doc_root (IIS only, if memory serves, PHP option).
Here are examples:

**applicationHost.conf** file:

`<application fullPath="C:\path\to\php\php-cgi.exe" arguments="-d doc_root=C:\path\to\webroot\ENV_DIR">`

and related **web.config**

`<add name="php" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\path\to\php\php-cgi.exe|-d doc_root=C:\path\to\webroot\ENV_DIR" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />`

In this way, you are able:

- set up instance-based environment variables (.env under Linux);
- able to include and/or use directories outside instance root folder.

Comment: Please mark the answer so that it can help others with similar problems.

Comment: Till have 19 hours to go to do that (not high enough rating, I guess)